# Is there a simple way of creating a list of identical objects without using a loop?

Tags: c#, loops

I currently have something like this:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Firstname { get; set; }

    public string Lastname { get; set; }
}

public List<Person> CreatePersons(int numberOfPersons)
{
    var persons = new List<Person>();

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPersons; i++)
    {
        persons.Add(new Person())
    }

    return persons;
}
```

I know that if I were to use an `array` then I could just do this:

```
var persons = new Person[numberOfPersons];
```

My question is:

- Is there a simple / direct way of creating a list of objects without using a loop?

I guess that an array probably does the exact same thing internally as using a loop to create this array but with a different notation. But that's not a concern for now, for this question I'm just interested in a simpler notation.

Comment: This question is difficult for me to understand. It seems like you ask a question (a way to create a number of identical objects without using a loop), propose a solution (use an array), and then pretend that solution doesn't exist. You want a simpler solution than a loop that isn't quite as simple as an array? Or...what?

Comment: Yes, I *have* to use a list and I know that there's a simple notation for arrays, I wanted to know if there exists a similar way of creating lists. Maybe create an array and convert it to a list?

Comment: An efficient way to create a `List` this way is to use its overloaded ctor that accepts an `IEnumerable<T>`, like so: `var list = new List<Person>(Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(i => new Person()));`

Comment: The array construct does not create objects, so it's not a solution.

Comment: Why *not* use a loop? Loops loop. That's what they do. Keep it simple.

Comment: @BrianRasmussen is absolutely right; a loop is *the* "simple / direct way" of doing this; it'll also be the most efficient. Sure, you can fake the same any number of ways, but... why? It just makes hard, ugly syntax and inefficient execution, when you *usually* want to achieve readability and performance (in that order, typically)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about,

```
var persons  = Enumerable.Range(0, numberOfPersons).Select(i => new Person()).ToList();
```

---

You could also do the the more obtuse,

```
var persons = Enumerable
        .Repeat<Func<Person>>(() => new Person(), numberOfPersons)
        .Select(f => f())
        .ToList();
```

---

In the end, I find the `for` loop easier to understand and it performs more quickly.

```
var persons = new List<Person>(numberOfPersons);
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPersons; i++)
{
    persons.Add(new Person())
}
```

Comment: @AleksanderRas I prefer the `for` loop, there is some loop inside the `Range`.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `ToList()` instead of `ToArray()`?

Comment: @MarcGravell: In most real-world scenarios, it will ot matter in terms of overall performance.

Comment: @Sefe that's odd, I work in the real world, and it matters measurably and demonstrably in my systems

Comment: @MarcGravell: It doesn't in mine.

Answer (score 1):

You already have a one-liner to construct an array, how about converting that into the list you want?

```
new Person[numberOfPersons].ToList();
```

Comment: but, they will all be `null`

Comment: Yes. Yes, they will.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use `System.Array.ConvertAll`, it still use `for` loop but you don' see it :)...

```
var persons = Array.ConvertAll(new Person[30], _ => new Person());
```

---

*n.b. this approach will allocate the array twice as it will allocate the resulting array and copy elements from input using the `for` loop...*